# Castle Active Record - one to many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, relationship

I try create many to relationship one to many in Active record.

```
[ActiveRecord("Users")]
public class User : ActiveRecordBase<User>
{
    private IList<PhotoAlbum> _albums = new List<PhotoAlbum>();

    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("ProfilId")]
    public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }

    [HasMany(Inverse = false,Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.Delete)]
    public IList<PhotoAlbum> Album
    {
        get { return _albums; }
        set { _albums = value; }
    }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Nick { get; set; }

}

[ActiveRecord("Profiles")]
public class Profil : ActiveRecordBase<Profil>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ProfilId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public int Sex { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public bool WithPhoto { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public bool HasPhotoAlbum { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("PhotoAlbums")]
public class PhotoAlbum : ActiveRecordBase<PhotoAlbum>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PhotoAlbumId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public int NumberOfPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

I am using sample from  http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/relations.html

it finished with this error:

> ActiveRecord tried to infer details about the relation User.Album but
>   it could not find a 'BelongsTo' mapped property in the target type

StrackTrace:

> at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.SemanticVerifierVisitor.VisitHasMany(HasManyModel
>   model)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.HasManyModel.Accept(IVisitor
>   visitor)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.AbstractDepthFirstVisitor.VisitNode(IVisitable
>   visitable)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.AbstractDepthFirstVisitor.VisitNodes(IEnumerable
>   nodes)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.AbstractDepthFirstVisitor.VisitModel(ActiveRecordModel
>   model)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.SemanticVerifierVisitor.VisitModel(ActiveRecordModel
>   model)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.ActiveRecordModel.Accept(IVisitor
>   visitor)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.AbstractDepthFirstVisitor.VisitNode(IVisitable
>   visitable)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.AbstractDepthFirstVisitor.VisitNodes(IEnumerable
>   nodes)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.RegisterTypes(ISessionFactoryHolder
>   holder, IConfigurationSource source, IEnumerable`1 types, Boolean
>   ignoreProblematicTypes)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(IConfigurationSource
>   source, Type[] types)    at SAMPLE_1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   E:\C# PROJECTS\STUDY\STUDY.ORM\Active Record
>
> > SAMPLE_1.PhotoAlbum

I think problem is here:

```
    [HasMany(Inverse = false,Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.Delete)]
    public IList<PhotoAlbum> Album
    {
        get { return _albums; }
        set { _albums = value; }
    }
```

If I omitted this property / relationship it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one profile has many photo albums, your `PhotoAlbum` class is missing a property:

```
[BelongsTo("ProfileId")]
public Profile Profile { get; set; }
```